# Why would "^(.*)$" in a RewriteRule apply to page assets when "^" does not?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

According to [a DreamHost article on enforcing HTTPS](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-How-do-I-force-my-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file-) the patterns "^" and "^(.*)$" result in different RewriteRule behavior, but I do not understand why.

According to the article, using "^" as follows "forces any http request to be rewritten using https":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The same article says that using "^(.*)$" instead of "^" in the RewriteRule "also forces directly linked resources (images, css, etc.) to use https".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Why would "^(.*)$" in a RewriteRule apply to page assets when "^" does not? Is there some element to the distinction beyond what the article mentions, such as relative vs. absolute URLs? How would the Apache HTTP Server even know that a resource is a page asset rather than requested directly?

By the way, I have interpreted "directly linked resources" as referring specifically to page assets, not HTTP links in the usual sense, so I have phrased my question accordingly, but if I have misinterpreted that then I would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho, it doesn't make any sense.

I know some hosting company have their own implementation of `mod_rewrite`. What's the difference in practice between these 2 rules?

In theory, they should do exactly the same thing as any URI will match `^` and `^(.*)$`

Moreover when the destination doesn't even use a partial match of the regexp (they use `%{REQUEST_URI}` and not `$1`).

It **would** make a difference if it was `^$` (basically, an empty string, so only the root URL would be redirected).

Direct or referred access doesn't change a thing either, unless you use a `RewriteCond` on `%{HTTP_REFERER}`

Comment: Yeah, the subpattern bit looked weird to me too. Perhaps that is a vestige of a previous version of the rule that referenced the subpattern. Either way, thank you for your insights. Answer accepted.